# Slutsky, Continuous mapping for uniform convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question- suppose I have a function f(x,$\hat \theta$), $\hat \theta$ is a consistent estimate for $\theta$ and therefore it holds $\hat \theta \rightarrow \theta$ in probability. Suppose f is continuous (in both arguments), then the continuous mapping theorem would yield $f(x,\hat \theta)\rightarrow f(x,\theta)$ for all x in probability, right?
And now suppose we have $f(x,\hat \theta)\cdot X$ with a random variable $X$, then Slutsky would yield $f(x,\hat \theta)\cdot X \rightarrow f(x, \theta)\cdot X$ in probability for all x. Correct?
How can I get this statement uniform in x (weak convergence would be enough)? Would it be enough to have this convergence: $f(x,\hat \theta)\rightarrow f(x,\theta)$ uniform in x?
Thanks!!

Comment: What does "uniform convergence" mean in this case?

Comment: I would like to have the convergence of stochastic processes, so pointwise convergence is not enough. I mean, are there different opportunities to define uniform convergence?